# dependency injection with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a service class :

```
public class MyService : IService
{
    private IRepoA repoA;
    private IRepoB repoB;

    public MyService(IRepoA repoA,IRepoB repoB)
    {
        this.repoA=repoA;
        this.repoB=repoB;
    }
}
```

my Controller depends on the MyService classL

```
public MyController : DefaultController
{
    IService myService;
    public MyController(IService service)
    {
        myService=service;
    }
 }
```

how do I inject the MyService class into the controller ?
should i do this  ? :

```
 Bind<IPostService>()
                .To<PostService>();

            Bind<IPostsRepository>()
                .To<SqlPostsRepository>()
                .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", 
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);


            Bind<IUserRepository>()
                .To<FakeUserRepository>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Ninject.Extensions.Mvc](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc). Read the read me and documentation. It has everything you need. From the looks of it, all you'll need is to properly setup your HttpApplication to inherit from `NinjectHttpApplication` and add the proper config code (all located in the readme/documenation)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to create your own controller factory that injects the dependencies for you and register that factory in Global.asax.

If you're using structure map, that could look like this:

```
public class IoCControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory   
{  
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)  
    {
        return (Controller)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Regardless of Ioc container you should be doing this to then find the rest of the dependencies down the chain. :)